How to choose the shortest path along the edge loop
I need to choose the shortest path between two points along the loop edge with python.
When I use bpy.ops.mesh.shortest_path_select(), the selected point will deviate from the edge loop like this

The result I hope for is to follow the loop edge like this

Do I need to make any restrictions or use other APIs
